# Adjoint of $0, \pm 1$ invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A \in \{0, \pm 1\}^{n \times n}$ be an invertible matrix and $B$ be the adjoint matrix of $A$. $A$ is a totally unimodular matrix if its determinant is $\pm 1$ and for all square sub-matrix $C$ of $A$, the determinant of $C$ is $0$ or $\pm 1$.

R. Gomory has shown that if $A$ is not totally unimodular, then it has a square sub-matrix $C$ such that the determinant of $C$ is 2. Is it possible to show that even if $A$ is not totally unimodular, there exists an entry in $B$ which is $\pm 1$? In other words, does there exist a first minor of $A$ which is $\pm 1$?

Comment: The result by Gomory you mention seems weird to me. The adjoint of $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is $-A$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I'm sorry, I made a mistake. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Random counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{-1&0&-1&1&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&-1&-1&1&0\\
-1&-1&1&1&0&-1&0&0\\
0&1&-1&-1&0&-1&0&0\\
1&0&-1&-1&1&1&0&1\\
-1&1&-1&0&1&0&1&1\\
0&1&0&1&-1&0&-1&-1}
$$
We have $\det(A)=-1$ and
$$
\operatorname{adj}(A)=\pmatrix{
-6&-14& 8&13&-5&16& 8&10\\
-5&-11& 6&10&-4&12& 7& 8\\
-6&-13& 7&12&-5&14& 8& 9\\
-2&-5& 3& 5&-2& 6& 3& 4\\
-7&-17& 9&16&-6&19&10&12\\
 3& 7&-4&-7& 2&-8&-4&-5\\
-2&-5& 3& 4&-2& 5& 3& 3\\
 2& 6&-3&-5& 2&-6&-3&-4}.
$$
Not sure if there are any smaller-sized counterexamples.

Comment: What if we restrict $A$ to have $det(A) = \pm 1$?

Comment: How did you come up with this counterexample? Did you use SAGE?

Comment: @MaheshSR I just ran a numerical experiment in Matlab. Oops. Sorry, not Matlab, but Octave (a Matlab clone).

Comment: Thanks for the help!